# Looking for sci-fi book about female bipedal feline spaceship captain earns earrings after successful missions

Tags: story-identification, novel

This series of books is based on a matrilineal space-traveling bipedal feline race. Every time they use super-speed space travel their perception is distorted and, when they slow back down to normal speed, they end up very tired, hungry, and thirsty, and their fur begins to shed excessively. The main character is a bit of a rogue, and the 'police' of her race are referred to as 'black britches.'

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103527/series-of-books-with-intergalactic-travel-trade (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 11):

The Chanur novels by C. J. Cherryh.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chanur_novels

Comment: Pedantic note: the police are *blackbreeches* rather than *blackbritches*. At least they are in my edition.